# Taking a probability class and I'm a bit stuck

Tags: probability

The probability that a family owns a smartphone is 0.81, that it owns a tablet is 0.58, and that it owns both a smartphone and a tablet is 0.44. what is the probability that a randomly selected family owns a smartphone or a tablet?

Comment: Firstly, define the events.
Namely,

A={a family owns a tablet}

B={a family owns a smartphone}

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

What is the total area in the following diagram?

---

[image]

Comment: Though I gotta admit that the $0.44$ segment must be twice as large, on the expanse of the $0.58-0.44$ segment...